# Variables in shell type session

Tags: linux, bash, shell

In the following script I get the size in bytes of a file, after I assign it to a variable called 'byteNuevo'. Then do a comparison where if 'byteAnterior'> 0 are subtracted 'byteNuevo - byteAnterior' and otherwise value is assigned 0.

The problem is that 'byteAnterior' has no value, if the value you had before 'my_text.txt', and hope I explained that this script does is show the value it had before 'my_text.txt' and that has now...

My example:

```
    echo -e "\n- Starting 1.sh script--\n"

if [[ ! -f my_text.txt ]]; then > my_text.txt; fi

byteOLD="$(cat somefile.storing.byteOLD.value.txt)"
echo "-- OK: so far byteOLD is: $byteOLD";

byteModified=$(stat -c'%s' my_text.txt)

echo "-- Now after modifying my_text.txt on the fly, bytes in variable byteModified are: $byteModified";

((byteDiferencia = (byteOLD > 0) ? byteModified - byteOLD : 0))
echo "  -- byteDiferencia is set to = '$byteDiferencia'"
```

Comment: It's not clear what's wrong. In what circumstances do you get incorrect output and how is it wrong?

Comment: something like this, I get the size in bytes of a file "which had before" and show you have now, should be modified. ej. script1.sh `byteOld=$(stat -c'%s' my_text.txt)
source ./code.sh` script2.sh `byteNew=$(stat -c'%s' my_text.txt)
echo 'second script '$byteNew' => ' $byteOld`

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps?

Case 1- where I'm putting a check that byteAnterior will never be less than 0 -OR i'll error out with a message.

```
[jenkins@giga_akssb12 tomcat]$ cat 1.sh ; cat my_text.txt; ./1.sh ;
#!/bin/bash

echo -e "\n- Starting 1.sh script--\n"
#As you didn't mention how u r setting byteAnterior, im assuming user will pass a parameter to this script.
byteAnterior="$1"
if [[ $byteAnterior -lt 0 || -z "$byteAnterior" ]]; then echo -e "\n   -- Pass parameter value >= 0.\n"; exit 111; fi

byteNuevo=$(stat -c'%s' my_text.txt)
echo "-- byteAnterior : $byteAnterior"
echo "-- byteNuevo    : $byteNuevo"
echo

#Ternary operator use
((byteDiferencia = (byteAnterior > 0) ? byteNuevo - byteAnterior : 0))

echo "  -- byteDiferencia is set to = '$byteDiferencia'"
Hi shenzi.

ed?

- Starting 1.sh script--


   -- Pass parameter value >= 0.

[jenkins@giga_akssb12 tomcat]$
[jenkins@giga_akssb12 tomcat]$ ./1.sh 0;
- Starting 1.sh script--

-- byteAnterior : 0
-- byteNuevo    : 16

  -- byteDiferencia is set to = '0'
[jenkins@giga_akssb12 tomcat]$
[jenkins@giga_akssb12 tomcat]$
[jenkins@giga_akssb12 tomcat]$ ./1.sh 12;
- Starting 1.sh script--

-- byteAnterior : 12
-- byteNuevo    : 16

  -- byteDiferencia is set to = '4'
[jenkins@giga_akssb12 tomcat]$
```

Case 2. If you want to set byteAnterior as 0 or something less than 0 or anything other than a valid number than >= 1. Then COMMENT out the check (if statement) and now byteDifferntia will be set to 0 via ternary operator. Run 1.sh and pass -1 as 1st parameter and you'll see:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -e "\n- Starting 1.sh script--\n"
#As you didn't mention how u r setting byteAnterior, im assuming user will pass a parameter to this script.
byteAnterior="$1"
#if [[ $byteAnterior -lt 0 || -z "$byteAnterior" ]]; then echo -e "\n   -- Pass parameter value >= 0.\n"; exit 111; fi

byteNuevo=$(stat -c'%s' my_text.txt)
echo "-- byteAnterior : $byteAnterior"
echo "-- byteNuevo    : $byteNuevo"
echo

#Ternary operator use
((byteDiferencia = (byteAnterior > 0) ? byteNuevo - byteAnterior : 0))

echo "  -- byteDiferencia is set to = '$byteDiferencia'"
Hi shenzi.

ed?

- Starting 1.sh script--

-- byteAnterior : -1
-- byteNuevo    : 16

  -- byteDiferencia is set to = '0'
```

Comment: 'byteAnterior' corresponds to the number of bytes that weighed before the file.

Comment: something like this, I get the size in bytes of a file "which had before" and show you have now, should be modified. ej. script1.sh byteOld=$(stat -c'%s' my_text.txt) source ./code.sh script2.sh byteNew=$(stat -c'%s' my_text.txt) echo 'second script '$byteNew' => ' $byteOld

Comment: I didn't get that part. I just showed.. how ternary will act. pls clarify -- what's no. of bytes that a file has before the file??

Comment: If, for example: 
1., I have the file text.txt 
Scan it 'text.txt' ... 
'byteOld' = 20 ... 
Scan it and modify 'text.txt' ... 
'byteNew' = 780 ... 
If I explain, of course thank you very much for your patience!

Comment: then, all you have to do is to store two output of stat -c on that file (before modification) and (after the modification) to two variables.. n use the same logic.

Comment: :) I don't understand Nuevo, anterior differntia .. etc. Lets my clarify.. see my next post.

Comment: What I'm trying to make is that if a file.txt amending shows the amount of bytes that weighed before and after

Comment: yea.. see my other post. which shows 3 cases. When my_text.txt doesn't exist. When it exists and gets modified, and keep modifying. Now, basically you are calculating OLD, MODIFIED (NEW) and then difference between then using ternary ? : operation.

Answer (score 0):

```
[giga@aks tomcat]$ rm my_text.txt

[giga@aks tomcat]$ ls -l my_text.txt
ls: my_text.txt: No such file or directory

[giga@aks tomcat]$
[giga@aks tomcat]$ cat 1.sh
#!/bin/bash

echo -e "\n- Starting 1.sh script--\n"

## Create a blank file if it doesn't exist.
## This will make byteOLD to hold 0 value. In future runs, it'll be append instead of overwriting.
if [[ ! -f my_text.txt ]]; then > my_text.txt; fi

byteOLD=$(stat -c'%s' my_text.txt)
echo "-- OK: so far byteOLD is: $byteOLD";

## Add something to the file in append mode >>.
## This will make byte2 to hold how much bytes you put there including last time if file exists.
echo -e "\n1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8\n9\10\n11111111\n22222222222\n" >> my_text.txt
byteModified=$(stat -c'%s' my_text.txt)

echo "-- Now after modifying my_text.txt on the fly, bytes in variable byteModified are: $byteModified";

#Ternary operator use
((byteDiferencia = (byteOLD > 0) ? byteModified - byteOLD : 0))
echo "  -- byteDiferencia is set to = '$byteDiferencia'"

[giga@aks tomcat]$


[giga@aks tomcat]$ ./1.sh

- Starting 1.sh script--

-- OK: so far byteOLD is: 0
-- Now after modifying my_text.txt on the fly, bytes in variable byteModified are: 44
  -- byteDiferencia is set to = '0'
[giga@aks tomcat]$
[giga@aks tomcat]$ ls -l my_text.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins dmadmin 44 Jun 12 15:17 my_text.txt
[giga@aks tomcat]$
[giga@aks tomcat]$ ./1.sh

- Starting 1.sh script--

-- OK: so far byteOLD is: 44
-- Now after modifying my_text.txt on the fly, bytes in variable byteModified are: 88
  -- byteDiferencia is set to = '44'
[giga@aks tomcat]$
[giga@aks tomcat]$ ls -l my_text.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins dmadmin 88 Jun 12 15:17 my_text.txt
[giga@aks tomcat]$
[giga@aks tomcat]$
[giga@aks tomcat]$ ./1.sh

- Starting 1.sh script--

-- OK: so far byteOLD is: 88
-- Now after modifying my_text.txt on the fly, bytes in variable byteModified are: 132
  -- byteDiferencia is set to = '44'
[giga@aks tomcat]$
```

Comment: Thanks! If I understand you, but I did not modify file is automatically modified by users

Comment: I agree. I was just showing you.. the trick. if someone else is changing that file.. than all you need is.. to store the value of LAST modified byte value to a file and read it when you run the script next time in byteOLD variable from the file i.e. byteOLD="$(cat somefile.storing.byteOLD.value.txt)" and calculate  byteModified and byteDifferentia as mentioned in the script. Make sure you put the byteModified to somefile.storing.byteOLD.value.txt i.e. echo $byteMofified > somefile.storing.byteOLD.value.txt;

Comment: well as actualize in my post? ^^^

Comment: The solution is this!`byteNuevo=$(stat -c'%s' "my_text.txt")
let "byteDiferencia = (byteAnterior > 0) ? byteNuevo - byteAnterior : 0"
echo $byteAnterior
if [ $byteDiferencia -ge 15 ]; then
 echo "Open the door"
fi
export byteAnterior=$byteNuevo
`

Comment: I see you changed the original post with the answer. One thing you missed is you're not putting echo $byteModified > somefile.storing.byteOLD.value.txt file and you'd need it for the next run (when byteOLD will read the last modified bytes it found during the script run).